# Replace HTML code with code from another page

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have got two `html` files, say `page1.html` and `page2.html`. In both files I have an `article` element. Now, on `page1.html` I would like to replace the content of the `article` element with that of `page2.html` using JavaScript (I don't want to use jQuery).

Currently, my solution is the following: When `page1.html` is loaded, I use the `fetch` method to get the content of `page2.html`'s `article` element. Then, when the user clicks a button, I call

```
article.innerHTML = newContent;
```

This does work fine so far, but recently I've read that `innerHTML` shouldn't be used to prevent XSS attacks. Obviously, I cannot set the property `article.textContent` since I've got "real" `html` code in my articles that I want to be interpreted as such. Another solution I could think of is to include the `html` code in the script file as a string. The downside of this method would be that I would have to change both `page2.html` **and** the script file, whenever I want to change the article.

Is there a recommended way to achieve what I want to do? Also, all the examples of XSS attacks I've read about seem to indicate that my specific use of `innerHTML` doesn't allow XSS attacks (since I fetch the code from a site which I control myself), but I don't just want to be like "I can't think of an XSS attack, so there'll never be one". Any insights about the danger of XSS attacks in this context?

Comment: if the html you are adding comes from your own source, moving it  by setting `innerHTML` creates no additional risk. If the article is added or editedable by a user, any risk arises at that point, so if you're comfortable with your source, you should be comfortable using it elsewere. MDN notes a new feature `Element.setHTML()` for insertions from dubious sources  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setHTML  but your source sounds safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have control over the content of this `page2.html` i.e. either you have a static or dynamic data which is not generated by the visitors visiting your webpages, then there is won't be any issue of XSS attack. In such cases you can confidently use `innerHtml` method.

But, in case the content of the `page2.html` contains the data from visitors (such as comments, posts, etc.) then only there is a chance of XSS attack. XSS attack is nothing but when your user put some JavaScript code for their advantage.
E.g. In case your page2.html contains comments, I can post comment like `Hello world! <script> alert("You have been hacked, transfer money to this bank to save your computer") </script>`. Or I can attach link to another vulnerable script which steal your user's data like cookie data.

For such use cases, please do not use `innerHtml` **directly**. The safe solution is either use `textContent` or sanitize your visitor's data (like the comment mentioned above) (Ref: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2019/11/29/javascript-sanitize-html/)

Answer (score 0):

try the following code here you have to call the **.text()** method in fetch response to get the actual HTML and insert it using `Element.innerHTML`

`fetch('DataPage.html') .then((res) => res.text()) //here you have to change the response into html text .then(res => {document.querySelector("#target").innerHTML = res;})`

Comment: I didn't ask how to include html code from another page using the `fetch` function. As I've written in my question I already have that part covered. Instead my question was specifically about the dangers of an XSS attack in this context and possibly other methods that don't bear that risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('./to/file'); ?>
```

This downloads the files with the thing. You could also do it with include.

```
<?php include "./to/file"; ?>
```